# Can I add methods to a Realm class in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I want to add a static function to a Realm model in my Swift iOS app. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It's possible.

You can add any number of class or instance methods to a Realm `Object` subclass. The only main limitation of this is you can't override the accessor methods for any properties backed by Realm.